# Connecting to ActiveMQ Artemis with QueueExplorer

Tags: activemq-artemis

I have a new install of ActiveMQ Artemis on a local virtual machine using Ubuntu 18.04. I'm trying to connect to it with a JMS client called [QueueExplorer](https://www.cogin.com/QueueExplorer/docs/activemq/connect-to-activemq.php).

[image]

```
Cannot read queues from machine 192.168.1.13/ (ActiveMQ).

StackTrace:  Cogin.ActiveMQ.AMQException: Could not connect to ActiveMQ: Unable to connect to the remote server
   at Cogin.ActiveMQ.Internal.JolokiaConnection.SendJsonRequest(String uriString, JToken requestJson)
   at Cogin.ActiveMQ.Internal.JolokiaConnection.RequestBrokerName()
   at Cogin.ActiveMQ.Internal.JolokiaRequest.GetMBeanObject(AMQMachineItem machine)
   at Cogin.ActiveMQ.Internal.JolokiaConnection.Execute(JolokiaRequest request)
   at Cogin.ActiveMQ.Internal.AMQBrokerProxy.GetBrokerInfo(IWorker worker)  
   at Cogin.ActiveMQ.Services.AMQBrokerService.GetQueuesTree(IWorker worker, Boolean showNonWritableQueues)
   at a8.a.e(IWorker A_0)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at ab.a.e()

Version: QueueExplorer Standard 4.3.15.26129 .Net Framework Version: 4.8.0 OS: Windows 10
```

I can ping the system successfully. The firewall is not enabled, and I can reach the web console. I followed [this guide](https://medium.com/@hasnat.saeed/setup-activemq-artemis-on-ubuntu-18-04-76bb4975308b) for setting it up, but I think I'm missing something. QueueExplorer needs Jolokia and OpenWire. The web console uses Jolokia, but the error in QueueExplorer complains about it.

When connecting to ActiveMQ with QueueExplorer, I didn't need to make any configuration changes. Are there additional steps in Artemis to allow a client to connect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's impossible to say with 100% certainty what the problem is since QueueExplorer is closed source software as far as I can tell. However, I can say with certainty that ActiveMQ Artemis *does* support OpenWire and it ships with Jolokia to expose its management beans (i.e. MBeans) via HTTP.

I believe the issue is that QueueExplorer expects to find in ActiveMQ Artemis the same MBeans as ActiveMQ 5.x and that simply isn't the case. While ActiveMQ Artemis supports many of the same features and functionality as ActiveMQ 5.x it is a fundamentally different architecture under the covers which is designed to provide a much higher level of performance and a protocol/API agnostic addressing model.

I believe the only solution here would be for the author(s) of QueueExplorer to update it to work with the ActiveMQ Artemis MBeans.

Comment: Interesting... So what queue explorer client do people use with Artemis?

Comment: I'd never actually heard of QueueExplorer until your question. I think most people simply use the web console that ships with the broker (which is available on port `8161` by default) if they want to explore queues. I've not really seen a need for a standalone, platform-specific application to do this kind of work, although if there is a need the management API is available via HTTP.

Comment: FWIW I sent an email to Cogin asking if they have any plans to support ActiveMQ Artemis.

Comment: I'm the developer of QueueExplorer. Justin is right - MBeans are different between ActiveMQ and Artemis. That's why it doesn't work. Unfortunately, that's not the only difference, and supporting all new features is not just a matter of parsing these MBeans in different way.